# INSERT INTO tableName SELECT * INTO tabkeName FROM tableName

Tags: sql

How will this below query execute and is there a better way to  write this query?

```
INSERT INTO tableName 
    SELECT * 
    INTO tableName 
    FROM tableName
```

Comment: If you want to copy the entire content from one to self or to another, there is hardly another way I'd say, you'd get a full table scan anyway. `postgresql` and `mysql` are entirely different RDBMS'es by the way

Comment: Simply copying a table can also be done using the DB tool without creating a SQL command on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```sql
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM someOtherTable;
```

Note that you should generally *always* explicitly specify which columns you want both for the insert and the select.  While your code might run as is, it is prone to breaking should the structure for either table change in the future.